# How do I start an Applet from a seperate Java Program?

Tags: java, netbeans, applet

I have a Java project where I am pulling tweets from twitter using the twitter4j library. A GUI will search by account, pull the tweets, let you remove some, then I want to launch an Applet which will iterate through the list of tweets and display them one at a time as scrolling text.

I want the display to be a separate window, preferably full screen, but I don't know at all how to go about it, and what I want is specific enough that I couldn't find any good examples for what I'm trying to do.

Right now, my GUI is running from GUIClass and imports Methods and they are both in the package "Twitterfeed" my displaying applet is in the package TwitterApplet (mostly because I don't know what i'm doing with netbeans, I much prefer Visual Studio and .net). I can run the Applet by itself by clicking "run file" and it shows up and scrolls the default text. The applet works, how do I start it from the GUIClass?

Comment: Why are you coding an applet (as opposed to a free-floating application, based on a frame)?  Do you realize that unless the data is coming from your own server, only a trusted applet will be able to access it?  As an aside, applets are very troublesome and should not be attempted by newbies (leads to madness, random yelping & persistent drooling).

Comment: *"I don't know what i'm doing with netbeans, I much prefer Visual Studio and .net"* 1) There are other free IDEs for Java.  Eclipse is highly regarded.  2) I'll bet it is a lot easier to embed executables into a web page or deploy them across multiple platforms using Netbeans, than using the other two you mentioned. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never worked with this API, but appletviewer is an executable (jre/bin/appletviewer.exe) and takes a set of options. I assume you can trigger it using

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
```

Especially that you don't care if it runs in a separate window.